# Retrieve data from mysql using ajax and populate input fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a page with a lot of input fields. I am using Jquery to get all of the values of the form at once using data: $("#profile").serialize().

Since my MySQL columns have the same name as my input fields. Is there an easy to select * from my db and load the results into the appropriate fields using jquery / ajax? Perhaps an example or a link?

Thanks,
Scott

Edit: Ok thanks for the help, but I am still a bit lost and not getting it to work, here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$.ajax({
url: "/profile_functions/profile_about_retrieve.php",
type: 'POST',
data: allFormFields,
success: function(){
    //console.log('done');
}
});

jQuery(#profile).find(":input").each(function(key, val) {
fieldName = jQuery(this).attr("name");
if(fieldName != "" && fieldName != undefined) {
    allFormFields[fieldName] = jQuery(this).val();
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

And a little test data from my db being echo'ed via json_encode

```
[{"key":"test","value":"9"}]
```

And html

```
<form id="profile" method="post">
<input type="text" name="test"
</form>
```

Comment: you can used map function i guess

Answer (score 1):

```
           jQuery(formId).find(":input").each(function(key, val) {

                fieldName = jQuery(this).attr("name");

                if(fieldName != "" && fieldName != undefined) {
                    allFormFields[fieldName] = jQuery(this).val();
                }
            });
```

Use the allFormFields array to send to the PHP endpoint

```
                  $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: allFormFields,
                        success: function(){
                            console.log('done');
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Ok the logic looks good but I am little confused. How would I specify the ajax url for this?

Comment: `url:url` to `url:'theURLlink.php'`